# How to open only one UncontrolledCollapse at the same time and close the others in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, reactstrap

I'm using the UncontrolledCollapse from https://6-4-0--reactstrap.netlify.app/components/collapse/ . But how can I only make one UncontrolledCollapse active at the same time when on click when there's multiple UncontrolledCollapse? at the moment, when I open one UncontrolledCollapse and also open the other UncontrolledCollapse, it will not close the previous UncontrolledCollapse..

This is what I have at the moment in my logic:-

```
export default function Header(args) {

return (
<Nav>
 <NavItem>
   <NavLink href="#" id="toggle-1">
      Toggle 1
   <NavLink>
   <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggle-1">
         Content 1 Here                                
   </UncontrolledCollapse>
</NavItem>
<NavItem>
  <NavLink href="#" id="toggle-2">
      Toggle 2
   <NavLink>
   <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggle-2">
         Content 2 Here                                
   </UncontrolledCollapse>
<NavItem>
</Nav>
)}
```

Comment: If you want to control the collapse, then why you're not using **Collapse** instead of  **UncontrolledCollapse** ?

Comment: @Pawan i'm not sure how I can merge it with a function component.. from the documentation, the normal collapse uses component but I'm using a function instead..

Comment: It is easy to convert function into the component, just add some js which is required to config collapse before **return** statement and replace **UncontrolledCollapse** with **Collapse** .

Comment: @Pawan is there any examples i can follow? I'm kinda lost in converting the function into the component

Comment: @Pawan Nevermind! i managed to get this right after going thru more carefully! :) cheers!